# How to use get_absolute_url by CreateView

Tags: django, url

I want the user to be able to immediately (without pressing the save button) return to the list view (index.html) when he's in the create view (create.html). But I'm not sure how to specify the link to accomplish this.

My create.html is as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Create new system? <small><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">Go to system list?</a></small></h2>

{% include 'snippets/form-snippet.html' with form=form %}

{% endblock %}
```

The system url conf is specified as:

```
app_name = 'system'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk_system>/', views.SystemUpdateView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('', views.SystemListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('create/', views.SystemCreateView.as_view(model=System), name='create')
]
```

My SystemCreateView is as follows:

```
class SystemCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'system/create.html'
    form_class = SystemForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        project_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
        obj.project = project
        return super(SystemCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SystemCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        project_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return kwargs

    def get_queryset(self):
        return System.objects.all() #filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SystemCreateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Create System'
        return context
```

The System model and get_absolute_url method are specified as follows:

```
class System(models.Model):
    project     = models.ForeignKey('solgeo.Project', related_name='systems', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    system_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('solgeo:system:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'pk_system':self.project.id})
```

Comment: what are you exactly trying to achieve ? you want a link to ListView or DetailView ?Cause the Absolute url is used for Detail view ? and you want just a link to return or a redirect when he submits the form ? and can you plz show us your url file stucture

Comment: I want a link in the create.html which allows the user to immediately return to index.html. I.e. the user doesn't need to press save to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the following solution:

```
class SystemCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'system/create.html'
    form_class = SystemForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        project_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
        obj.project = project
        return super(SystemCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SystemCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        project_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
        kwargs['project_id'] = project.id
        return kwargs

    def get_queryset(self):
        return System.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SystemCreateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        project_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        context['title'] = 'Create System'
        context['project_id'] = project_id  # add project_id to context
        return context
```

Now I can access the context variable project_id in my create.html template, i.e.:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Create new system? <small><a href="{% url 'solgeo:system:list' project_id %}">Go to system list ?</a></small></h2>

{% include 'snippets/form-snippet.html' with form=form %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have no other namespace linking to this url file like that

```
path('system/', include('system.urls')),

 {%  url 'list' %} #the url to listview
```

but if your main urls link to this file look like that

```
path('system/', include('system.urls', namespace='system')),

  {%  url 'system:list' %} #namespace go first : url name
```